# Assining column name string to 2d numpy array columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array off this form (it is much larger with 2000 columns)

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I would like to add a string of values onto this array as column titles in order to index the array using text in a manner similar to that below:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", dtype=None, encoding=None, delimiter="\t").reshape(-1, 3).T

#  Sting of headers to insert
namesstring = ['a100','bt200','c300']

# Need to assign hear to numpy columns like this
print(array)

a100 b200 c300
1    4    7
2    5    8
3    6    9
```

Note that the original data is in a text file that I import as an NumPy array using `np.genfromtxt`. How would I assign the string as column index names to the numpy array ?

Comment: Tell us more about `array`, its  `shape` and `dtype`.  Beware that adding a string row to an array that is `int` or `float` will turn the whole thing into string dtype.  Also this change does  not allow you to "index" the columns by name.  A sample of the `data.txt` might help, since you are fiddling with the `genfromtxt` output (reshape and transpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `vstack()` method in `numpy`:-

```
array=np.vstack((namesstring,array))
```

Comment: Btw......If this answer helped you then try considering accept this answer......Thanks:)

Comment: Time constraint had to wait another 4min before I could accept it. You were too fast ;D